# Can Razor code blocks output to a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've seen examples in Razor, like this:

```
@{
    if(something == true)
    {
      <p>This</p>
    }
    else
    {
      <p>That</p>
    }
}
```

I thought that Razor code blocks aren't supposed to output anything to the view, and that expressions defined using @() were for that. So how is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the details about both types of expressions in [this page](http://razorcheatsheet.com/#csharp)

Statement `@()` is called explicit expression, and above link describes it like this:

> The explicit impression should be used when you want to do something
>   that might otherwise confuse the parser. For instance, if you need to
>   access a variable in the middle of a string or if you want to do
>   calculations/modifications to the output.

Statement `@{}` is called multi-statement code block. Above link describes it like this:

> A Razor code block starts with a combination of the @-character and
>   the {-character and ends with the } character. Inside of this, you're
>   now writing C# code.

So short answer is that multi-statement blocks can be used and often are used to render some HTML. And you need to use explicit expression (`@()`) when compiler might be confused between HTML and C# code.